# Filtering data does not work properly on docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have dockerized my Flask project, It gets `added_at` as a datetime and filters my products:

```
def post(self):

  args = request.get_json()
  products = Product.query

  args = {k: v for k, v in args.items() if v}
  
  added_at = args['added_at'] if 'added_at' in args else datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
  products = products.filter(Product.created_at >= added_at).all()

  return len(products), 200
```

My problem is that when I add a record in products table and search data, It returns new products correctly.

But on docker :

1. I run `docker-compose up -d`
2. Add a row manually to database (on mysql)
3. Search products => it does not return new rows, even if the created_at field is for yesterday
4. I restart my app service and then search => it works correctly!!

It seems that my database is not synced with app, after few hours it returns data and my db is mysql.

Here is my docker-compose of app service:

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  app:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    image: app
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    networks:

      - app-network
```

Comment: Can you include the complete code of the view that handles the search request? Also what ORM are you using?

Comment: I added the code, but works correctly without docker, and with docker works after restarting docker app @sytech